# Mastercard payment integration how to redirect to a link after complete the payment

Tags: javascript, mastercard

I need to redirect to a URL after the payment completed

I used the code provided in the documentation

```
<script src="https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/checkout/version/52/checkout.js"
                 data-error="errorCallback"
                data-cancel="cancelCallback" 
                 data-complete="completeCallback"
                 data-afterRedirect="restorePageState"
                 return_url="{{url('confirm_is_paid/'.$Recipt->id.'/'.$Recipt->security_code)}}"
              >
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function errorCallback(error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
}
function cancelCallback() {
            console.log('Payment cancelled');
}

Checkout.configure({
        merchant: 'my_merchant_id',
        order: {
                amount: function() {
                        //Dynamic calculation of amount
                          return {{$Recipt->final_price}};
                },
                currency: 'EGP',
                description: 'Ordered goods',
             id: Math.random()
        },
        interaction: {
                operation: 'PURCHASE', // set this field to 'PURCHASE' for Hosted Checkout to perform a Pay Operation. , AUTHORIZE
                merchant: {
                        name: 'AAIB TEST',
                        address: {
                                line1: '200 Sample St',
                                line2: '1234 Example Town'
                        }
                } }
});

function restorePageState(data)
{
    window.location.replace("{{url('confirm_is_paid/'.$Recipt->id.'/'.$Recipt->security_code)}}");
}

function completeCallback(resultIndicator, sessionVersion) {
              window.location.replace("{{url('confirm_is_paid/'.$Recipt->id.'/'.$Recipt->security_code)}}");
           }

Checkout.showPaymentPage();

</script>
```

everything is working correctly except I can't redirect after the payment completed
so what can i do to made it redirect to a url after the payment compleated ?

Comment: Do you have any event when this is finished?

Comment: Hi @Zayed, Is your restorePageState function is working after getting redirected from Payment Interface ?

Answer (score 3):

**The following is valid and has been tested for MPGS version 56 to 58**

I hope my answer finds you well.

The issue you are mentioning is still being faced today unfortunately, and it is so weird that the MPGS team still did not fix it.

First of all, I would like to point out to the following from the documentation of MPGS:

```
Requesting a Hosted Checkout interaction is a simple process:

Request a checkout session using the Create Checkout Session operation. The request should include payment and interaction data, as well as completion instructions. A sample curl snippet for the Create Checkout Session operation is shown below.

curl https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/api/nvp/version/57 \
-d "apiOperation=CREATE_CHECKOUT_SESSION" \
-d "apiPassword=$PWD" \
-d "apiUsername=merchant.<your_merchant_id>" \
-d "merchant=<your_merchant_id>" \
-d "interaction.operation=AUTHORIZE" \
-d "order.id=<unique_order_id>" \
-d "order.amount=100.00" \
-d "order.currency=USD"
```

This would return a `session.id` that you should include in your `Checkout.configure` javascript function, in which is missing from your current sample code.

The tag missing parameter in your `Checkout.configure()`:

```
 session: { 
                id: '<your_create_checkout_session_ID>'
                },
```

Now to dig in and reach the answer. In every part of the MPGS documentation, they recommend the usage of `data-complete="completeCallback"` or `data-complete="http://[your domain]/receiptPage"`, the `completeCallback` was not good enough for our implementation as we are using `Checkout.showPaymentPage();` -> which is also poorly documented by MPGS, and the `data-complete` or `return-url` url was not working, as we would reach the payment page and never redirect from the receipt page of MPGS to our servers.

After digging deeper into the documentation, we noticed the request parameters `interaction.cancelUrl` and more importantly **`interaction.returnUrl`**  in the **Create Checkout Session** documentation.

From the MPGS `Create Checkout Session` api documentation.

```
interaction.returnUrl  URI
The URL to which you want to return the payer after completing the payment attempt.
```

```
interaction.cancelUrl  URI
The URL to which you want to redirect the payer's browser if they cancel their payment.
```

and as you'll notice the above have similar functionalities to `data-complete` and `data-cancel`

**Finally the solution**

For the `Checkout.showPaymentPage();` you'd have to pass these parameters in the initial `request session request`

```
curl https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/api/nvp/version/57 \
-d "apiOperation=CREATE_CHECKOUT_SESSION" \
-d "apiPassword=$PWD" \
-d "apiUsername=merchant.<your_merchant_id>" \
-d "merchant=<your_merchant_id>" \
-d "interaction.operation=AUTHORIZE" \
-d "order.id=<unique_order_id>" \
-d "order.amount=100.00" \
-d "order.currency=USD"

-d "interaction.returnUrl=<your_returnUrl or data-complete url>"
-d "interaction.cancelUrl<your_cancel_url> or data-cancel url>"
```

Adding the extra parameters would fix the redirect issue when you'd want to redirect back to your website. You will find the following under `Obtain the Payment Result`

```
To return the payer to your shop site, you must either:

provide interaction.returnUrl in the Create Checkout Session operation, OR
define the complete callback in the Hosted Checkout request. See Basic Callbacks.
```

This should be refactored to say that `interaction.returnUrl` should be used in `Checkout.showPaymentPage()`  and `complete callback` should be used in `Checkout.showLightbox()`

I hope this helps and saves a ton of times and emails for new visitors.

References:

[MPGS-Implementing a Hosted Checkout Integration](https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/hostedCheckout/integrationModelHostedCheckout.html?locale=en_US#x_HCObtainThePaymentResult)

[MPGS-Create Checkout Session](https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/apiDocumentation/rest-json/version/latest/operation/Session%3A%20Create%20Checkout%20Session.html?locale=en_US)

[MPGS-Checkout configuration](https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/apiDocumentation/checkout/version/latest/api.html?locale=en_US)

Comment: Thank you, I was stuck on this issue for 5 days.  You just give me new life LOL

Comment: hi, do you mind helping me out. i have a problem with my PAY operation, i cant redirect the response back to user since it is happening on the gateway. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74767666/nodejs-res-redirect-changes-the-content-displayed-but-not-the-url

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation,

> If you provide a URL instead of a function in a callback, the payer will be redirected to this URL when the event is triggered.

Instead of callback function in `data-complete="completeCallback"` try providing your redirect URL.

Also, the following is mentioned in the docs

> In order to be notified via the complete callback you must:
>
> - Create a checkout session using the Create Checkout Session operation.
> - Pass the session.id into Checkout.configure().
> - Provide a callback.complete function or URL.

Check your callback satisfies all these conditions.

---

Source: https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/hostedCheckout/integrationModelHostedCheckout.html

Comment: I tried (Create Checkout Session) but it always returns
error.cause=INVALID_REQUEST&error.explanation=Request+does+not+match+any+supported+operation&result=ERROR
can you help with this by showin what is the body needed to be send  ?

Comment: @MohamedZayed the error is likely because of the field `operation: 'PURCHASE'`. Make sure that your merchantId is enabled to perform this operation.